# Adding new object to the Firebase database with Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just added Firebase to my Android application, configured my dependencies.
And now I'm trying to add new object to my RealDataBase, but no thing is saved.

Here is my code:

```
        private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.child("Remorqueurs").setValue(rq);
```

Is something missing?

PS: `rq` is an object.

Comment: Most likely you don't have writer permission on the database. See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/19721/detect-errors-when-writing-a-value-on-android#t=201611151808457853214) for how to detect this.

Comment: exactly it was a problem of permission. Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear you got it fixed. I'll vote to close as a "unable to reproduce", as this is unlikely to be found by people in the same situation as you are.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing missing in the syntax, it's all perfect. You can alternatively try for this `mDatabase.push().setValue(rq)` and check if a new child is getting created under the root or not.

If the issue still persist then there must me some other issue. You can check if your device has Google Play Services 9.0+.

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase dashboard:

=> Database => Rules and setting

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
  }
}
```

Or create a user registration if necessary.

[image]